# php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] too far down the tree

Tags: php

I have multiple sub-domains within the document_root.  And multiple folders/classes within those sub-domain folders.  I need something that will help me with my include_once paths, but $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] goes too far down.  And if I were to use this, and transfer the website folder later, all my include_once paths will/might break.

Hope my question is clear... Any recommendations?

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is, access classes, that are located in different folders, from different files.  When it works for some files, it'll break in others, because of the way I'm writing the include statements.

Ie. class test{include_once '../Data/employee.php';}
A file that will include the class test, will work.  But say another file, from a different directory, includes the class test.  It'll break.  Because the other file can be 3 folders deep, instead of just one.

Comment: May be you mean $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Comment: woops, I did mean server :), thanks for spotting that typo.  But that being said... do you have a solution?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will contain document root on every system. So, I see no problem in using it.

Comment: On the QA server, the website exists in www/test/, so $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] will return www/, then I just add test.
On the prod server, the website exists in www/apache.  So when I do $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT) it will return www/, then add on test.  which is wrong.  it needs to add on 'apache'.  And say I move the website to a diff server, with the sub-domain 'iis', it'll be broken too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) per sub-domain (inside the `<virtualhost>`) using [Apache's `php_value` directive.](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: I'm worried about the client moving servers.  If they move server, they'll need to reconfigure the new apache server using your solution.  Is there a way without apache configurations?

Comment: you can have that in .htaccess files in the directories themselves.

Comment: I did not do exactly this, but I assume it's correct, since relocating the folder to the real document root did what I wanted.  So essentially, if I told Apache to use a different document root, in theory this answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem:

```
$relpath = "";
$tempvarrelpathdir = explode("/",dirname($SERVER['PHPSELF']));
for($i=count($tempvarrelpathdir); $i>0; $i--) if($tempvar_relpathdir[$i] != '') $relpath .= "../";
```

It will get the relative path to root dir...